# Getting started with GSAP

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gsap

I'm trying to do my first tween with **GSAP**, and nothing's happening, even when I've tried to use example code.

I have a php file with the following code:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  #green {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #0D9C02;  
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="green"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/greensock/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/greensock/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var logo = document.getElementById("green");
    TweenLite.to(logo, 1, {left:"600px"});
  });
</script>
</body>
```

All I get though is a static green square. I must be missing something fundamental - but what?? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution: needed `position: relative;` in the css to work.

Answer (score 1):

`position` property in css is missing

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nzrca6s1/)

HTML elements are positioned `static` by default.
The left property has no effect if the element is `position:static`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a TimeLine first where you can attach your tweens. You can use either TimelineLite or TimelineMax (there is slight difference between two).

**Use following code-**

```
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.flashtalking.com/frameworks/js/gsap/1.18.0/TimelineLite.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  #green {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #0D9C02;  
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="green"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/greensock/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/greensock/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    theTimeline = new TimelineLite();
    var logo = document.getElementById("green");
    theTimeline.add(new TweenLite.to(logo, 1, {left:"600px"}));
  });
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The element needs to have a position value of relative, absolute or fixed to be able to move it tweening the left value. I would further suggest not tweening the left property but the x property. since x and y properties use transform instead it will be better performance.